# Talend AWSS3 component - iterate over files only once

Tags: amazon-s3, talend

I would like to use AWSS3 (`cAWSS3`) component in Talend (Routes) and fetch the files for further processing. But it seems it iterates over the files over and over again.
I do not want to delete the files after they are processed.

Is it possible to configure the component to stop after the first iteration?

Comment: Can you try with setting `maxMessagesPerPoll` parameter in the advanced settings ? It's described here : http://camel.apache.org/aws-s3.html

Comment: It does not help since I would like AWSS3 to iterate over files only once without deleting them but it does this again and again!

Answer (score 0):

`cAWSS3` uses underlying Apache Camel `aws-s3` component to implement S3 storage polling. This means you may use any of the Camel component's configuration in the corresponding Talend component's advanced properties to tweak it.

It seems **repeatCount** property is what you're looking for. By default it equals to 0 meaning the consumer runs forever. Please look into [Camel AWS S3 reference](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/aws-s3-component.html) for more details and other advanced properties.